# Better way to write the following jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im quite new to javaScript/jquery. 
I wrote the following code to toggle a mobile Navigation but i am quite sure there is a simple way to combine the to following code blocks.
i would appreciate advice how to write this a better, sleeker way.
Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var width = $(window).width();
    if(width <=500){
        $("nav").addClass("mobile").removeClass("desktop");
    }
    else{
        $("nav").removeClass("mobile").addClass("desktop");
    }

});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    if(width <=500){
        $("nav").addClass("mobile").removeClass("desktop");
    }
    else{
        $("nav").removeClass("mobile").addClass("desktop");
    }
});});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply create a single function and call it twice:

```
function changeClasses() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if(width <=500){
        $("nav").addClass("mobile").removeClass("desktop");
    }
    else{
        $("nav").removeClass("mobile").addClass("desktop");
    }
}

$(document).ready(changeClasses);
$(window).resize(changeClasses);
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe better use css media queries...

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
    .desktop {
        width: or another rules...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it into a separate function which will clean it up a bit:

```
function toggleClass() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if(width <=500) {
        $("nav").addClass("mobile").removeClass("desktop");
    } else {
        $("nav").removeClass("mobile").addClass("desktop");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    toggleClass();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    toggleClass();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always add the event once on resize then trigger the resize event. I added a namespace to the event so that it will not conflict with any other window resize events when we trigger it.

```
$(window).on('resize.load', function() {
  var isMobile = $(window).width() < 500;
  $("nav").toggleClass("mobile", isMobile).toggleClass("desktop", !isMobile);
}).trigger('resize.load');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r6myh0z8/

Comment: I should have noted that with toggleClass the second parameter is used for determining whether the class should be added or removed. If this parameter's value is true, then the class is added; if false, the class is removed. So by determining the boolean isMobile we can pass whether or not the class should be added or removed. Just saves the If/else statements